# How do I convert a scrapy.http.headers.Headers type to a string type

Tags: python, scrapy

When I use Python Scrapy, I need to get the content of response.headers and convert it to json format, but the type of response.headers is not a string.

Here's my code：

```
def start_requests(self):
    url = example.com
    yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.example)

def example(self,response):
    print(type(response.headers),response.headers,sep='\n\n')
```

result:

```
<class 'scrapy.http.headers.Headers'> 

{b'Date': [b'Sun, 09 Feb 2020 11:40:32 GMT'], b'Content-Type': [b'text/html; charset=utf-8'], b'Last-Modified': [b'Thu, 06 Feb 2020 12:46:22 GMT'], b'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': [b'*'], b'Expires': [b'Sun, 09 Feb 2020 11:25:33 GMT'], b'Cache-Control': [b'max-age=600'], b'X-Proxy-Cache': [b'MISS'], b'X-Github-Request-Id': [b'7404:79E4:296ECA:2ED9E5:5E3FE9D4'], b'Via': [b'1.1 varnish'], b'Age': [b'20'], b'X-Served-By': [b'cache-sjc10050-SJC'], b'X-Cache': [b'HIT'], b'X-Cache-Hits': [b'1'], b'X-Timer': [b'S1581248432.467223,VS0,VE0'], b'Vary': [b'Accept-Encoding'], b'X-Fastly-Request-Id': [b'ea8aae70ba4691d060aeca764f445527279e23e7'], b'Cf-Cache-Status': [b'DYNAMIC'], b'Expect-Ct': [b'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"'], b'Server': [b'cloudflare'], b'Cf-Ray': [b'562591aedc3ded7b-SJC']}
```

When I use `json.dumps(response.headers)`, it always prompts `TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not bytes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With response.headers Scrapy returns byte literals. You have to convert the dict content to string literals. The following code should do the job:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import scrapy

class Example(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'    

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'http://www.example.com'
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.example)

    def example(self,response):
        print(self.convert(response.headers))

    def convert(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, bytes):  return data.decode('ascii')
        if isinstance(data, list):   return data.pop().decode('ascii')
        if isinstance(data, dict):   return dict(map(self.convert, data.items()))
        if isinstance(data, tuple):  return map(self.convert, data)
        return data
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which answers my question to some extent.

Answer (score 9):

I just came across the same issue and found this one here:

[scrapy/http/headers.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/http/headers.py)

The code is very simple then:

```
page_headers = response.headers.to_unicode_dict()
```

Worked nicely for my cases so far.